# refresh a page once using php

Tags: php, web

is there a way to refresh a page once in php?
Like I want to put it in an if statement

```
if(sometheing)
{
    refresh
}
```

I know `header("refresh: 3");` refreshes it every three seconds but I want something that only does it once.

Comment: Did you got the answer. I am going through the same scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code within your if condition

```
header( "Location: index.php" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the condition if its true then refresh the page.

```
<?php $refresh = 'Yes'; // lets assume the refresh condition is yes  
if(isset($refresh) &&  $refresh == 'Yes'){ // or simply you can check by isset only no need to check for $refresh == 'Yes'
         header("Location:current_page.php");
         $refresh= false; // if you don't want to refresh the page again without any condition comes true.
         } 
?>
```